# swift - return and pass multiple arrays and an Int via Segue

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I'm nearly there with a small basic program I'm writing (still learning) and I've hit a roadblock.

I can now pass 1 array between 2 view controllers and successfully print it when I hit a button in the 2nd one.

However, what I really want to do is pass 2 arrays and an Integer, created from a function on the first VC and have them accessible via the 2nd VC.

Code for 1st VC is here :

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "goToWorkout" {
        if let destVC = segue.destination as? WorkoutViewController {
            destVC.bothArrays = self.testFunction()
        }
    }
    //Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    //Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}

func testFunction() -> [String] {
    let randomArray1 = ["blah","blah","ploop"]
    let randomArray2 = ["alan", "john"]
    let randomInt = 5
    return BOTH ARRAYS AND INT TO SEND TO THE NEXT VIEW CONTROLLER?
}

@IBAction func goPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToNextVC", sender: self)
}
```

and 2nd VC here :

```
class WorkoutViewController: UIViewController {

    var randomArray1 = [String]()
    var randomArray2 = [String]()
    var randomInt = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func nowButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print(randomArray1)
        print(randomArray2)
        print(randomInt)
    }
}
```

I can get it working with just one array but I need more than one array and a value to be passed!  I've tried playing around with it (e.g. trying '-> [String], [String], Int) but no luck

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: You should can tuples, (array1,array2,int)

Comment: Don’t use the func to assign but instead do it directly in prepare(...) for each property separately. DestVC.randomArray1 = randomArray1 and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use a `tuple` to include several variables of different types in a single variable. You should pass the tuple including all 3 variables in your `performSegue` function as the `sender` argument, then assign them to the relevant instance properties in the `prepare(for:)` method.

If you want to keep the function for generating the variables, you should change the return type of the function to a tuple that can fit the 3 variables.

```
func testFunction() -> (arr1:[String],arr2:[String],randInt:Int) {
    let randomArray1 = ["blah","blah","ploop"]
    let randomArray2 = ["alan", "john"]
    let randomInt = 5
    return (randomArray1, randomArray2, randomInt)
}
```

Then assign the return value of `testFunction` to the sender input argument of `performSegue`:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToNextVC", sender: testFunction())
```

Assign the variables:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToWorkout" {
        if let destVC = segue.destination as? WorkoutViewController, let variablesToBePassed = sender as? (arr1:[String],arr2:[String],randInt:Int) {
            destVC.randomArray1 = variablesToBePassed.arr1
            destVC.randomArray2 = variablesToBePassed.arr2
            destVC.randomInt = variablesToBePassed.randInt
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @nc14 you can't put line breaks in comments, so the actual error messages are missing from your comment

Comment: sorry should be there now!

Comment: @nc14 updated my answer, that should fix the first error. For the second error as I've already stated in my answer you should declare all 3 variables in a way that they are accessible from the scope where you're calling `performSegue`

Comment: Yes perfect - that fixed the first error, i see what you did there.  On the second point, i've tried calling "testFunction" inside the 'goPressed' function just above performSegue but that doesn't work - how do you use your approach if you need to use a function to generate the variables?  (sorry this might be really easy!)

Comment: @nc14 check my updated answer, I've modified it to use `testFunction` to generate the variables

Comment: Right okay that makes sense - because the function is 'sending' it the data?  That builds now, but when I hit the button on the 2nd VC, both arrays and the Integer are blank (the Int prints the default one which is 0 but the other 2 just show [], [], in the console, any ideas?

Comment: @nc14 did you check that inside `prepare(for:)` both if statements are reached as expected?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that - I've added a little button to test the variables from the function are printing in the initial VC and that works fine but still getting blanks on 2nd VC [],[], 0 on separate lines

Comment: @nc14 you can set up breakpoints in Xcode to check whether certain pieces of code are ever executed. Or you can simply put print statements inside the if statement in question and check whether the printing happens or not.

Comment: Thanks - I’ve just added print statements and nothing is printing in the console when I trigger the segue - what causes that though? Very odd?

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, you can refactor your function to return a tuple, and then use that to pass to your other view controller:

```
//This is the tuple data type we use to pass 2 string arrays and an Int
typealias  parameterTuple = ([String], [String], Int)


func testFunction() -> parameterTuple {
    let randomArray1 = ["blah","blah","ploop"]
    let randomArray2 = ["alan", "john"]
    let randomInt = 5
    return (randomArray1, randomArray2, randomInt)
}


func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToWorkout" {
        if let destVC = segue.destination as? WorkoutViewController {
            //refactor WorkoutViewController to have a parameters property 
            //of type parameterTuple, split out the tuple and pass each part to
            //a different property in your WorkoutViewController
            destVC.parameters = testFunction()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks - could you elaborate on the "refactor workoutviewcontroller" part?  I've tried to set a property like this "parameters = ([String]), [String], Int) () but that says "cannot call value of function type any" and 'cannot invoke with no arguments'